# Fix your connection is not private (ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error) on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ssl, certificate

I have been getting the ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error on chrome for some websites. It doesn't happen with every single website but happens on a majority of them.

Here are a few things I have noticed. This only happens with the chrome web browser. I have tried used Edge and every website works perfectly fine. Going to Incognito mode does not solve the problem for Chrome. However, signing into Windows with a different user profile and then opening up chrome makes the chrome browser work perfectly fine.

I have tried the following to fix it: clear cookies, cache, etc, update Chrome and Windows, checked antivirus software, disabled extensions, uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome (fully including hidden files).

Looking further into the error details, one thing stood out to me. On chrome, the issuer of the certifcation authority is always VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 whenever chrome shows the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, regardless of the website. For example, if I open up [quora.com](https://quora.com) on the chrome web browser, it shows:

**Issued By:**

Common Name (CN)    VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority  - G5

Organization (O)    VeriSign, Inc.

Organizational Unit (OU)    VeriSign Trust Network

**Validity Period:**

Issued On   Sunday, March 15, 2020 at 9:41:43 PM

Expires On  Tuesday, March 15, 2022 at 9:41:43 PM

However, on the edge browser [quora.com](https://quora.com) shows the following:

**Issued By:**

Common Name (CN)    R3

Organization (O)    Let's Encrypt

Organizational Unit (OU)

**Validity Period:**

Issued On   Sunday, November 13, 2022 at 11:20:31 AM

Expires On  Saturday, February 11, 2023 at 11:20:30 AM

Not sure if this has any relevance to the problem, but thought I'd give all the facts and what I noticed so that somebody can help me troubleshoot. It is becoming really annoying and a waste of time solving this issue so I would appreciate it if someone has a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to delete the user's Google Chrome profile? Uninstalling and Reinstall Chrome wouldn't delete the user's Google Chrome profile. The fact you are getting an invalid expired certificate with Chrome and not Edge indicates a persistent malware infection within Chrome.

Comment: BLUF: `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` actually should have an expiration of July 16 2036

Comment: I tried using a different user profile and incognito mode and that didn't seem to fix the problem. Yeah, I noticed that about the expiration date, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I wanted you to delete the entire user profile for Chrome.